# How to delete rows in a table created from a Spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Basically, I would like to do a simple delete using SQL statements but when I execute the sql script it throws me the following error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nmissing 'FROM' at 'a'(line 2,
>   pos 23)\n\n== SQL ==\n\n                DELETE a.* FROM adsquare a
>   \n-----------------------^^^\n"

These is the script that I'm using:

```
sq = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.rpc.message.maxSize','1536').config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",str(shuffle_value)).getOrCreate()
adsquare = sq.read.csv(f, schema=adsquareSchemaDevice , sep=";", header=True)
adsquare_grid = adsqaureJoined.select("userid", "latitude", "longitude").repartition(1000).cache()
adsquare_grid.createOrReplaceTempView("adsquare")   

sql = """
    DELETE a.* FROM adsquare a
    INNER JOIN codepoint c ON a.grid_id = c.grid_explode
    WHERE dis2 > 1 """

sq.sql(sql)
```

**Note**: The codepoint table is created during the execution.

Is there any other way I can delete the rows with the above conditions?

Comment: In Spark, all the Data abstractions are immutable. you got to have your UDF to populate Ur new data DF that excludes  the field you are not interested.

Comment: UDF is too expensive for this simple task

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not delete rows from Data Frame. But you can create new Data Frame which exclude unwanted records.

```
sql = """
    Select a.* FROM adsquare a
    INNER JOIN codepoint c ON a.grid_id = c.grid_explode
    WHERE dis2 <= 1 """

sq.sql(sql)
```

In this way you can create new data frame. Here I used reverse condition `dis2 <= 1`

Answer (score 13):

Dataframes in Apache Spark are immutable. SO you cannot change it, to delete rows from data frame you can filter the row that you do not want and save in another dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

You can not delete rows from Data Frame because Hadoop follow **WORM( write once read many times)** instead you can filter out the deleted records in the SQL statement will give you the new data frame.