# How to create a connection with Oracle using Spark Scala without loading data?

Tags: sql, oracle, scala, apache-spark

Is there any standard Scala class/Object to create a simple connection with oracle database (using JDBC) but without loading a specific table ?
I just want to create a simple connection then pass some query (create/update, etc.) and finally close the connection.

i have seen a code like :

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .load()
```

But it loads a specific table as mentionned in .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename").

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) are all the JDBC examples. 'write' creates the table automatically, no need to explicitly create the table, if table already behavior depends on "mode" like overwrite, append, error, no-op.

If you want to update the table like delete selected rows via spark you could create a new DF with desired rows only and write it in overwrite mode, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515193/how-to-delete-rows-in-a-table-created-from-a-spark-dataframe)